# BitmapFactory.decodeStream causing "read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)" error

Tags: android, bitmap, sd-card

I have a piece of code where use a 2-stage image loading for loading images from the SDCard.

First I use the method `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` to just decode the image bounds and after I use it to really load the (sampled) image.

Here is my method. I think it's derived from an example I saw here someday, but I don't remember the thread.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(Context c, Uri uri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = getSourceStream(uri, c);

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    fis = getSourceStream(uri, c);

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, options);
}
```

It always worked perfectly running on real devices, but now I need to run some tests in AVD, but when I hit the line `return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, options)` (the second `decodeStream`) I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
```

The reading/writing sdcard permissions are set.

What should be done?