# Getting lseek failed: EBADF (Bad file number) Exception in reading bitmap from InputStream

Tags: android, bitmap, inputstream, android-bitmap

I'm getting **" lseek failed: EBADF (Bad file number) exception"** issue while creating the bitmap from InputStream. This issue is occuring in some specific devices only. for me I'm getting this error in "Nexus 5" device and my client getting this issue in "Samsung S3" device. I'm not getting the issue in my Samsung s3 device. The question is similar to [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499123/bitmapfactory-decodestream-causing-read-failed-ebadf-bad-file-number-error) and
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584755/read-failed-ebadf-bad-file-number)

But I'm unable to debug and fix this issue. Below is my code in reading the Input stream and bitmap.

```
InputStream in = getImageStream(index);

 public InputStream getRawImageStream(long position) throws IOException {
    super.seek(position);
    long length = super.readLong();
    LOG.debug("getRawImageStream(0x%x) len:%,d", position, length);
    if (length > MAX_IMAGE_SIZE) {
        throw new IOException(String.format("Excessive image length %,d", length));
    }
    return new RandomAccessFileInputStream(this, length);
}

public static long copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output, long length) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    long count = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int chunk = BUFFER_SIZE;
    while (count < length) {
        if (count + chunk > length) {
            chunk = (int) (length - count);
        }
        if (-1 == (n = input.read(buffer, 0, chunk))) {
            break;
        }
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;

}

@Override
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    long alen = Math.min(len, endPosition - file.getFilePointer());
    if (len <= 0) {
        // At end of stream / section
        return END_OF_SECTION;
    }
    return this.file.read(b, off, (int) alen);
}
```

Please check my code and let me know your thoughts.Any help would be highly appriciated.